# Calculate $\int_0 ^\infty\int_0 ^\infty e^{-x^2 -y^2} dx dy$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I want to calculate the following double integral:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^2 -y^2} \ \mathrm{d}x \ \mathrm{d}y$$

I used the change of variable $x=r\cos\theta$,  $y=r\sinθ$, so I get

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-r^2}r \ \mathrm{d}r \ \mathrm{d}\theta$$ $$\frac{-1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-r^2} \ \mathrm{d}\theta$$

I'm stuck here. How can I calculate that integral?

Thanks.

Comment: You didn't change your bounds. Since $(0,\infty)^2$ is the first quadrant, you are now integrating over  $r\in(0,\infty)$ and $\theta \in (0,\pi/2)$. That is sufficient now; you can use u-substitution to knock out the $r$ integral, and the $\theta$ integral is trivial.

Comment: [Gaussian integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral).

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that. So I get $\frac{-1}2 \int_0 ^\infty -1 dθ$, so  the result is $\frac{π}{4}$. Is this correct?

Comment: @ruplop yes it is. It should be $\int_0^{\pi/2}$ you made a typo.

Comment: Yes! Is there a relationship between $I = \int_{0}^{\infty } e^{-x^2} $ and $I' = $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^2 -y^2} \ \mathrm{d}x \ \mathrm{d}y$$? $  I know that $I= \frac {\sqrt{π}}{2}$ and $I'= \frac {π}{4}$, so $I= \sqrt{I'}$. Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

For $$\int_0^\infty e^{-r^2}r\,{\rm d}r$$

Consider the substitution $u=r^2$

---

For the record, your integral should be

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^\infty e^{-r^2}r\,{\rm d}r\,{\rm d}\theta$$

Comment: @Downvoter: What's the issue?